# How to get a Sitecore item from a fake site

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sitecore

In a unittest I am using `Sitecore.FakeDb`.

I have extended the sample to add the fakeSite with a rootPath, which gets set.
If I try to retrieve the rootItem with `Context.Site.GetItem(rootPath)` it returns null.

```cs
[Test]
public void FakeSite()
{
    // create a fake site context
    var fakeSite = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Sites.FakeSiteContext(
      new Sitecore.Collections.StringDictionary
        {
                { "name", "website" }, { "database", "web" }, { "rootPath", "/sitecore/content/NL" }
        });

    // switch the context site
    using (new Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher(fakeSite))
    {
        var rootItem = Context.Site.Database.GetItem(Context.Site.RootPath); // returns null

        Assert.IsNotNull(rootItem);
        Assert.AreEqual("website", Sitecore.Context.Site.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("master", Sitecore.Context.Site.Database.Name);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @marek-musielak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add fake item to your fake db first.

See sample code from github here:

```cs
public void HowToCreateSimpleItem()
{
  using (Sitecore.FakeDb.Db db = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Db
    {
      new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbItem("Home") { { "Title", "Welcome!" } }
    })
  {
    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item home = db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
    Xunit.Assert.Equal("Welcome!", home["Title"]);
  }
}

public void HowToCreateHierarchyOfItems()
{
  using (Sitecore.FakeDb.Db db = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Db
    {
      new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbItem("Articles")
        {
          new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbItem("Getting Started"),
          new Sitecore.FakeDb.DbItem("Troubleshooting")
        }
    })
  {
    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item articles =
      db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Articles");

    Xunit.Assert.NotNull(articles.Children["Getting Started"]);
    Xunit.Assert.NotNull(articles.Children["Troubleshooting"]);
  }
}
```

https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/Creating-a-Simple-Item

https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/Creating-a-Hierarchy-of-Items

Comment: Sounds good, ofcourse. I have used that, I am now trying to combine the two.

Answer (score 1):

As @Marek said, I didn't create an item, just set the rootPath to which item it should point.

This is the working test.

```cs
    [Test]
    public void FakeSite()
    {
        using (Db db = new Db("web")
        {
            new DbItem("NL") { { "Title", "NL Site" } }
        })
        {
            Item siteItem = db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/NL");

            // create a fake site context
            var fakeSite = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Sites.FakeSiteContext(
                new Sitecore.Collections.StringDictionary
                {
                    { "name", "website" }, { "database", "web" }, { "rootPath", "/sitecore/content/NL" }
                });

            // switch the context site
            using (new Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher(fakeSite))
            {
                Assert.AreEqual("website", Sitecore.Context.Site.Name);
                Assert.AreEqual("web", Sitecore.Context.Site.Database.Name);

                var rootItem = Context.Site.Database.GetItem(Context.Site.RootPath);
                Assert.IsNotNull(rootItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Although I realize that Site means the CM/CD site. Not the MultiSite I was looking for.